# Replacing HDD with SSD without loosing/reinstalling original OS and Installed Softwares

Tags: windows, hardware, hard-drive, solid-state-drive

I have a windows 10 machine with HDD installed.I need to replace this HDD with SSD.

My question is,

is it possible to migrate the OS and the softwares already installed HDD  to SSD without reinstalling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the OS from one hard drive to the other. However you have to have a Dock attached to the computer then you can clone it..

Or you can have it cloned by a repair technician.